# getting a row count using a subquery

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

im currently using a subquery of an outer query to get the number of people who ordered a book ina  certain time. Im a part of the way there. My current subquery is:

```
select count(cust_id)
from a_bkorders.order_headers
where date_format(order_date,'%Y/%m') = Prevmonth(curdate(),1)
or date_format(order_date,'%Y/%m') = PrevMonth(curdate(),2)
group by cust_id;
```

which returns

```
count(cust_id)
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
4
14
```

I want a count of the rows returned which is 13 but i dont think surrounding the entire subquery in count() is going to do the trick. Im sure this is an easy fix but im not seeing it.
Thanks.

(PrevMonth is a function i have written)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to just do a count of the returned results. Not sure if this will cause problems with your outer query, but if you want to post that with some sample data I can build a fiddle and fix it up real quick.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(first_count) -- first_count is the alias i gave the subquery count. so its a count of the number of rows returned in the subquery's count
FROM(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(cust_id) AS first_count
    FROM a_bkorders.order_headers
    WHERE date_format(order_date,'%Y/%m') = Prevmonth(curdate(),1)
        OR date_format(order_date,'%Y/%m') = PrevMonth(curdate(),2)
    GROUP BY cust_id
) AS temp; -- all tables need to have an alias
```

you may not even want to do a count in your subquery... unless you need the number of books that those customers ordered as well. you could just `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) FROM....` to get the number of unique id's.

Comment: Thanks I couldnt really get my head around setting an alias for each subquery and was getting lost in that. This really helped sort everything out for me and I got it running exactly how I needed to.

Comment: of course! you can select the alias given in a subquery in your outer query, so it makes it useful at times. if all you are trying to get is the number of customers then i would recommend doing a distinct count of id's and not worry about doing an additional select from the query (easier to read and will run faster)

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want `count(distinct)` rather than `count()`:

```
select count(distinct cust_id)
from a_bkorders.order_headers
where date_format(order_date,'%Y/%m') = Prevmonth(curdate(),1) or
      date_format(order_date,'%Y/%m') = PrevMonth(curdate(),2);
```

Comment: yea, I kinda eluded to that in my answer. if he just wants the number of customers that made an order it should be a count of distinct id's

Comment: your answer is different than mine, so I wasn't saying its the same or anything.. just saying i was kinda leaning that way too with my answer as well (saying to count the id) but wasn't sure because the OP may want the number of books ordered as well